# Jest and NestJs how how to close the prisma connections

Tags: jestjs, nestjs, prisma

I have an issue, where my test suites are not closing connections to prisma when I use app.close or prisma.$disconnect. This means that I am running into the error when running my test suites.

```
Error querying the database: db error: FATAL: sorry, too many clients already
```

As well as

```
Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.

This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't stopped in your tests. Consider running Jest with `--detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot this issue.
```

This is the blueprint to what my typical test suite looks like:

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { INestApplication } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppModule } from '../../src/app.module';
import { PrismaService } from '../../src/prisma.service';

describe('Description', () => {
  let app: INestApplication;
  let prismaService: PrismaService;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule],
      providers: [PrismaService],
    }).compile();

    app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
    prismaService = moduleFixture.get(PrismaService);
    await app.init();
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await prismaService.$disconnect();
    await app.close();
  });

  it('Should do something', async () => {
    expect(1).toEqual(1);
  });
});
```

My implementation of Prisma Service

```
import { INestApplication, Injectable, OnModuleInit } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

@Injectable()
export class PrismaService extends PrismaClient implements OnModuleInit {
  async onModuleInit() {
    await this.$connect();
  }

  async enableShutdownHooks(app: INestApplication) {
    this.$on('beforeExit', async () => {
      await app.close();
    });
  }
}
```

I was using TypeOrm previously, and app.close() sorted out this issue, however after moving to prisma I cannot for the life of me figure out how to overcome this.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Could you please share the implementation for `PrismaService` as well? Also, are you running the tests in parallel with `jest`?

Comment: @TasinIshmam I have edited my question to include my PrismaService implementation. 

I am not running in parallel, I am running them with the runInBand option

Comment: I tried recreating your setup (`PrismaService` and the test suite, with some basic CRUD tests), but could not replicate the issue. Could you try adding `await prisma.$disconnect();` before closing the app in the `enableShutdownHooks`?. I also found [this comment](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/5007#issuecomment-740803749) with a user having similar issues to yours, you could take a look.

Comment: However, I don't have anything concrete to suggest, sorry. If you could create a [bug report](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/new/choose) with steps to reproduce the problem, we could take a better look at the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I found the solution in the the [thread](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/5007#issuecomment-740803749) you supplied

I explicitly set the connection limit to 1 and it seems to be working now. Previously I had been attempting to increase the connection limit, but this seems to have done the trick

If you want to add an answer I will accept it. Thanks :)

Comment: Sure, wrote an answer!

Comment: After adding a few more tests, the issue is now back. I think I am going to have to log a bug report.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that, yes please create an issue with reproduction, we will try to help!

Comment: I have submitted my [bug report](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/10119). If it is something really stupid I am doing, apologies in advance.

Comment: Thanks, @Brendan, I'll see if someone can take a look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to the latest major version of Prisma has sorted out this issue. In my case the exact version I am now using is 3.4.2.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/5007) which discusses connection issues in various contexts (including tests, serverless environments, etc).

One workaround (That worked for the original poster of this question) is to manually set the connection limit by appending `?connection_limit=1` to the connection string.